Extract particular value from middle of a column which is separated by '/' and '//'
One of my table column has data stored like this. Some of the values start with single '/' and some of them with double '//'
/etc/data/env/source/sourcename1/filename1/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp
//etc/data/env/source/sourcename2/filename2/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp
//etc/data/env/source/sourcename3/filename3/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp
/etc/data/env/source/sourcename4/filename4/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp
/etc/data/env/source/sourcename5/filename5/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp

I need to extract the value of filenames from the column. Tried charindex(), left() functions but failed to get the desired value.
Desired output
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5


Please add the actual query you tried.

What is your SQL Server version?

How do you identify the filename? Just search for '/filename' and continue up to the next '/'? Always the sixth '/' delimited substring if you collapse '//' to '/' where it occurs?

Using 12.0.2000.8 version

Please try the following solution based on tokenization via SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY is tokenizing tokens column as XML.
XQuery .value() method gives us a desired output by retrieving 7th token.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('/etc/data/env/source/sourcename1/filename1/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp'),
('//etc/data/env/source/sourcename2/filename2/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp'),
('//etc/data/env/source/sourcename3/filename3/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp'),
('/etc/data/env/source/sourcename4/filename4/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp'),
('/etc/data/env/source/sourcename5/filename5/file-arrivaltimestamp/file-processedtimestamp/file-archivedtimestamp');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/';

SELECT *
    , c.value('(/root/r[7]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,'//',@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



id
result




1
filename1


2
filename2


3
filename3


4
filename4


5
filename5




The above query has worked :). Thank you

Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

I tried to do it with string_split() but epic fail. So I did it using Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K() and it worked a champ:
WITH cteFiles(newfilepath)
AS
    (
        SELECT REPLACE(filepath,'//','/')
        FROM teest
    )
SELECT *
FROM cteFiles
CROSS APPLY Scratch.dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(newfilepath,'/') ca
WHERE itemNumber = 7;

Output:
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5


string_split with positional argument should work fine, but it requires sql server 2022

Just another option using JSON
Example
Select FileName = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(SomeCol,'//','/')) )B(NewStr)
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([NewStr],'json'),'\/','","')+'"]') ) C(JS)   

Results
FileName
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5


The query is working and giving the desired output. Thank you

@karen If it solved your problem, ACCEPT it.   It acts as a small thank you to the contributors and indicates to others that the issue has been resolved.
